# Why is javabeans data source returning error?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, ireport

I'm following this tutorial:
http://javabeansinjasper.blogspot.com/

I'm encountering difficulty when testing the java beans data source on iReport.  I have packaged my app jar via mvn package and added it on iReport classpath.

My factory class looks like this:

```
public class JasperReportFactory {

    private static Vector proposalReports;

    public static void setProposalReports(ProposalReport report) {
        proposalReports = new Vector();
        proposalReports.add(report);
    }

    public static Collection getProposalReports() {
        return proposalReports;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

> The method don't return a valid Array or java.util.Collection!

Any ideas will be appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JasperReportFactory.getProposalReports()` is returning `null`

iReport calls `JasperReportFactory.getProposalReports()` but without first calling `public static void setProposalReports(ProposalReport report)`

## Solution:

You need to make sure that that your  `private static Vector proposalReports;` is not `null` (in fact in blog you provided they are creating the Vector in the  `getStudentList()`)

**Example**

```
public static Collection getProposalReports() {
    if (proposalReports==null){
        setProposalReports(new ProposalReport()) //mockup for iReport
    }
    return proposalReports;
}
```

While posting note that `Vector` is old java 1.4, you should consider to use [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) with type definition.

```
private static List<ProposalReport> proposalReports;
```

see [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: thank you for this, any ideas why the fields won't get populated on iReport even though the connection data source is now successful?  I'm expecting I can now drag and drop fields but they are none.

Comment: @yin03 If you don't get the fields automatically (retrive fields), create them manually (right click fields nodes, add field), give same name and class as in your bean.